# Minimize the difference between set of values

Tags: optimization, loss-functions

I have a parametric function that produce set of values. I want to optimize the function's parameters so the the output values are equal as possible regardless their values. for example:

```
y = f(x; a,b) ;  x,y are vectors with N values, a,b are single value paramters
```

I am using non-derivative optimization since the function is complicated and non-derivative. Currently I am trying with the Genetic Algorithm.

What is important for me is that `max(y) - min(y)` is minimum. However, when I chose the previous criteria as an objective function, the optimization became very slow (more iterations needed to reach a reasonable error). However, if I tried to minimize the standard deviation of the output values, the optimization algorithm reaches a reasonable solution much faster.

My questions:

- Why I am facing this behavior? I mean my goal is to minimize `max(y) - min(y)`. However, when I minimize `std(y)`, I got a better `max(y) - min(y)` in less iterations. Is this expected? why?
- In my case, what is the most logical objective function should I use? `std(y)` is good but I was wondering if there was a better one

Comment: Did you try to compute what `(x, y)` values in your dataset wear `min(y)` and `max(y)`? Possibly your $f$ function shape is unfit to bring these values together. By using `std(y)`, you make the algorithm work not only on these extreme values, but all values together.
Does the `std(y)`criterion approach provide the same actual results for `max(y) - min(y)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe there is misunderstanding, the function itself produces a set of values stored in vector called y. So, min(y) and max(y) are the result of the same x.. Or I could not understand your comment

Comment: OK - Indeed, I initially misunderstood, now it is clear.
Can you add some details on your dataset? Such as how many `(x, y)` you have in your statistics (I guess you have multiple couples). When you say that the `std(y)` approach provides better results for the `max(y) - min(y)` metric, is it on `max(max-min)` or else?

Comment: Are you `min(y)` and `max(y)` values initially close to 0? How does it behave with, say, `-1 + min(y)/max(y)` (avoiding division-by-zero errors)?